# Are the normal coordinates of a Riemannian manifold compatible with its original charts?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

[image]

As above, any Riemannian manifold can be equipped with normal coordinates. My question is whether those normal coordinates are compatible with its original coordinates charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, otherwise they wouldn't be called normal **coordinates**. This follows from the fact that $\exp_p$ (restricted to an appropriate neighborhood) is a diffeomorphism and so is $\varphi$. Any diffeomorphism $\varphi \colon U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ from an open subset of $M$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defines a coordinate system $x^1,\dots,x^n$ on $U$ (where $\varphi = (x^1,\dots,x^n)$). The fact that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism (with respect to the natural smooth structure on $U$ as an open subset of $M$ and the natural smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$) guarantees that the coordinates are indeed compatible with the smooth structure on $M$.